# How to clone wordpress site without clobbering posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a development (local, offsite), staging, and production wp site.  I can use the 'Duplicate' plugin to clone the site from one location to the other.

All well and good, but if I'm working on it in either staging or development and someone posts content (or adds page content) on the live site, that will get clobbered when I dup the site from the staging or development site.

Same goes for development to staging, if I have someone else working on it.

How do you coordinate clones?  The 'Duplicate' plugin explicitly states it will overwrite the target DB, even if I've unchecked posts.  It just wipes out the entire database and replaces whatever is in the archive.

Do any of the cloners make an attempt at merging content?  Or a differential backup?

**A thought:**

Sans a packaged solution, the only thing I can think of (and I'll have to try it out, I guess) is go to the target site before migrating, dump the 'post/comment/post-meta/comment-meta' tables in mysql, do the migration, and then re-import the tables after cloning from the exported file.

Seems messy.

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/mergebot-database-merging-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily clone the wordpress website by installing [All In One Wp Migration plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) without making any harm to your existing posts, If needed you can increase the upload size by going into constants.php file on line no 308 and can replace 2 with 4 or 5 or 6.

```
define( 'AI1WM_MAX_FILE_SIZE', 2 << 28 );
```